# Spring Android not working with Gradle

Tags: java, android, spring, gradle

I'm trying to use Spring Framework for Android in my project. I'm using IntelliJ with Gradle build tool. I'm following spring quick start tutorial. 
My gradle.build file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
    compile "joda-time:joda-time:2.2"
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-auth:1.0.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-core:1.0.1.RELEASE'
}
```

And when I try to do smth like this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
       RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
   }
}).start();
```

i get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate
```

Ofc I have in my imports 
`import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;`

Comment: org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate is not in your class path

Comment: @Amith How can I fix that in intelliJ?

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ ?

Comment: @ben75 version 13.0.1

Comment: Try with Android Studio, and make sure to correctly import the Gradle build.

Comment: @peter Can't change IDE. What's wrong with IntelliJ?

Comment: Not sure if and how well it's supported at this time.

Comment: Try to use 0.7 gradle plugin but I don't think this a problem. What version of gradle do you have?

Comment: Same problem in Android Studio.
Eventually had to download .jar and include it in project using:

compile files('libs/spring-android-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar')
    compile files('libs/spring-android-rest-template-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar')

Comment: I've Finally Made it work by running: Gradle clean task, and Sync Project with Gradle Files.

Answer (score 0):

For someone that faced the same issue. In my case, the problem was this: There was a library in my project that had spring as dependency, so in its build.gradle, there is this line:

```
compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M1'
```

But for some misterious (I don't really know why) the only way I could resolve the issue was adding the above dependency also in my root module. At first this dependency was not in my root module, because only the mentioned library uses RestTemplate class.

Comment: How to add this dependency in root module??